# Seg fault: C++ Quicksort using vectors and iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement quicksort using C++ containers and iterators.

I am new to C++ STL.

I am getting a seg fault. For all my C programs I always used valgrind to figure out situations like this but right now its not helping. Any tips/suggestions/solutions will be appreciated.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <fstream>
> #include <vector>
> #include <iterator>
> #include <algorithm>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> void print(vector<int> A){
>     for(vector<int>::iterator i = A.begin(); i != A.end(); i++)
>         cout << *i << " ";
>     cout<<endl;
> }
>
> vector<int>::iterator Partition(vector<int>::iterator l, vector<int>::iterator r){
>     int x = *l;
>     vector<int>::iterator i = l + 1;
>     for(vector<int>::iterator j = l + 1; j <= r; j++){
>         if(*j < x){
>             iter_swap(j, i);
>             i++;
>         }
>     }
>     iter_swap(l, (i - 1));
>     return i - 1;
> }
>
> void QuickSort(vector<int>::iterator l, vector<int>::iterator r){
>     if (distance(l, r) <= 1) return;
>     vector<int>::iterator p = Partition(l, r);
>     QuickSort(l, p - 1);
>     QuickSort(l + distance(l, p), r);
> }
>
> int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
>     if (argc != 2){
>         cout << "Usage: ./Sort <file_name>" << endl; //<file_name> refers to a file of integers where each line contains a number
>         return EXIT_FAILURE;
>     }
>
>     ifstream infile(argv[1]);
>
>     vector<int> A;
>     int num;
>     while(infile >> num){
>         A.push_back(num);
>     }
>     //print(numbers);
>     int n = 0;
>     print(A);
>     QuickSort(A.begin(), A.end());
>     print(A);
>     //cout << n << endl;
>     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
> }
> ```

Comment: `j <= r` in `Partition` is suspicious, most likely wrong; end-of-range iterator may not be dereferenceable.

Comment: If you use a debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, and use the minimal array of two elements, you should be able to locate your bug very easily. Hint: dereferencing `end()` is undefined behavior, and a guaranteed crash.

Comment: `Partition(l, r)` may return `l`, then back in `QuickSort` you compute `l-1` - which may go out of range and exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I wasn't aware that end() is undefined, any suggestion about how I can modify the code to not rely on end() but still achieve the same functionality using iterators